# I dont know why the timer in my code makes the animation duplicate its repaint() location

Tags: java, swing, timer, action

I'm using swing timer for my animation in japplet.
I'm having an issue on understanding how timer really works.

I came up with this code(this is a small part of it):

```
Action actionListener2 = new AbstractAction() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
                timer = new Timer(500,this); 
                timer.start();
                System.out.println("S");
                p.moveSquare(p.SnakeHeadX,p.SnakeHeadY+p.SnakeHeadH);
                p.eatBlueSquare(p.SnakeHeadX,p.SnakeHeadY);

            }
        };
```

Answer (score 3):

No, don't create a new Timer inside of the ActionListener as that will repeatedly create many many timers. Instead simply move your square inside of the Timer's ActionListener and call `repaint()`. Have you read the Swing Timer tutorial? If not, I urge you to Google it and give it a look.

Answer (score 2):

> A Swing timer (an instance of javax.swing.Timer (in the API reference documentation)) fires one or more action events after a specified delay. Don't confuse Swing timers with the general-purpose timer facility that was added to the java.util package in release 1.3
>
> Timer basically a java thread which started after a delay or instantly and perform assigned task.

you should move your Timer creation from actionperformed function as mentioned above.

```
  Timer timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
                {
                     System.out.println("S");
                     p.moveSquare(p.SnakeHeadX,p.SnakeHeadY+p.SnakeHeadH);
                     p.eatBlueSquare(p.SnakeHeadX,p.SnakeHeadY);
                }
            });
    timer.start();
```

for more details go through 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html